# Getting incomplete data when running 6 ignite servers

Tags: join, ignite

I am running 6 Ignite servers on version 2.7.5. The problem is when I am hitting queries using my client API I am not getting all records. Only some records are coming. I am using partitioned cache. I don't want to use replicated mode. When queried with DBeaver it show all records have been fetched.

The following code is used to fetch the data:

```java
public List<Long> getGroupIdsByUserId(Long createdBy) {
    final String query = "select g.groupId from groups g where g.createdBy = ? and g.isActive = 1";
    SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(query);
    sql.setArgs(createdBy);
    List<List<?>> rsList = groupsCache.query(sql).getAll();
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<?> l : rsList) {
        ids.add((Long)l.get(0));
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Ignite Version - 2.7.5

Client Query method

And the join Query is :

```
    final String query = "select distinct u.userId from 
    groupusers gu "
                + "inner join \"GroupsCache\".groups g on gu.groupId = g.groupId 
"
                + "inner join \"OrganizationsCache\".organizations o on 
gu.organizationId = o.organizationId "
                + "inner join \"UsersCache\".users u on gu.userId = u.userId 
where "     + "g.groupId = ? and "
                + "g.isActive = 1 and " + "gu.isActive = 1 and " + 
"gu.createdBy 
    = ? and " + "o.organizationId = ? and "
                + "o.isActive = 1 and " + "u.isActive = 1";
```

For the join query Actual records in db is 120 but with ignite client  only 3-4 records are comming .and they are not consistent. sometime it comes 3 records and some time it is 4 records. And for query

```
select g.groupId from groups g where g.createdBy = ? and g.isActive = 1
```

actual records are 27 but comming records are sometimes 20 sometimes 19 and sometimes complete. Please Help me with this and with collocated joins..

Comment: What is the Ignite version used? Can you show your queries?

Comment: public List<Long> getGroupIdsByUserId(Long createdBy) {
      final String query = "select g.groupId from groups g where 
    g.createdBy = ? and g.isActive = 1";
      SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(query);
  sql.setArgs(createdBy);
  List<List<?>> rsList = groupsCache.query(sql).getAll();
      List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
      for (List<?> l : rsList) {
       ids.add((Long) l.get(0));
      }
      return ids;
     }

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
   <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.5</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Can you please update your post with this information?

Comment: Does it work ok with `REPLICATED` mode? I'm not saying you should use it, it's for the sake of experiment. We should isolate the issue because this behavior looks strange, as far as I can see you don't use joins, you shouldn't have faced collocation issues.

Comment: May be you r right .But can you tell me the best way to collocate these servers. I this your suggestion will help me. @VladimirPligin

Comment: And one more thing @VladimirPligin the query i am firing is a join between two tables located on two different servers.

Comment: @shubhendrasen, I would be able to answer how to collocate your data if you update the question with your actual query (with joins).

Comment: @VladimirPligin question updated

Comment: @alamar question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this would mean that your affinity is incorrect.

Apache Ignite assumes that your data has proper affinity, i.e. when joining two tables, rows to join will always be available on the same node. This works when you either join by primary key, or by a part of primary key which is marked as affinity column (e.g. by `@AffinityKeyMapped` annotation). There's a [documentation page about affinity](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation).

You can check that by setting `distribtedJoins` connection setting to `true`. If you see all the records after that, it means you need to fix your affinity.

Comment: Strange thing happned to me this evening. i have replicated the same senario on my laptop. I have created 6 ignite servers and loaded the cache in them. now a query without joins not giving me complete details but when i queried count(*) using dbeaver it show all data have been cached. But the query select distinct g.groupId,g.groupName,g.description from groups g where g.createdBy = ? is still giving partial data.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yup. Thing is the query i am trying is without joins.

Comment: Wait. that query without joins is now working fine. now .

Comment: I have also changed the way client interacts. now i am using connection object.

Comment: Thanks Alamar and vladimir